# Unable to get Text from a Span tag in WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="style1" valign="top">   URL :    </td>
<td class="style3">
<span id="lblPresenter" class="bord">https://testurl.net</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

enter code here

```
we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lblPresenter']"));
System.out.println(we1.getAttribute("InnerHTML"));
              //I am getting Null as result
                            or
 System.out.println(we1.getText());
               //I am not getting any result
```

**strong text**
I need to get URL from the above source code .
If any body have a solution please let me know .

Comment: What does below line returns:-  System.out.println(we1.getText());                  Does it returns empty text or some null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, XPath should be avoided because it's slower and more error prone. This is a simple scenario that doesn't require an XPath. You can do the same thing using `By.id()`

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("lblPresenter"));
System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

One issue with your `we1.getAttribute("InnerHTML")` is that the `i` in `innerHTML` should not be capitalized. Please try the above code and see if that works. If not, please post the results/errors.

Comment: I am new to selenium thats why making these silly mistake. Thanks again

Comment: @Som if this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. If not, please post more information on what did not work.